# Assembler Code Add-Function: Register does not exist

Tags: assembly, addition

I´m ought to add two numbers of Register 1 and Register 2 and save the result in a Register 3. I have to do it with Assembler Code and the ADD-Function (ADDS DST, S1, S2IMM). The problem is that, whenever i try to execute this code, i get an error which says that R3 does not exist.
Can sb help me pls?

This is what i tried: ADDS R3, R1, R2

Comment: What architecture are you programming for?

Comment: Please add some info to your post : architecture used, code section, error message, ...

Comment: Looks like ARM to me. Which is strange, because it does indeed have an `R3`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem when using "ADDS R3, R1, R2". However it worked with a space between the quotation marks and the ADDS, like that: " ADDS R3, R1, R2".

Comment: Are you talking about inline assembly in C or something, and as part of an asm statement with multiple instructions?  What compiler?  Actual assembly doesn't use quotes around instructions.  In GNU C, you normally need a statement separator like a newline, not just a space, such as `asm("adds r1, #1 \n\t"` `"adds r3, r1, r2" ::: "r1", "r3");`